# How to embed code in a text field and concatenate it with a string in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, concatenation, ascx

In a text field in ASP.NET how would I concatenate a string with a variable, method call, or database entry?

For example:

```
Text="<some string> + MethodCall()"
Text="<some string> + variable"
```

Comment: Could you show some code of what you have so far?

Comment: I answered my own question below. I posted in hopes of helping someone else how had the same question and couldn't find the answer. If you have any other solutions that might be better, feel free to post. I'll update my question to better suit what I was look for.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate a string with a database entry in a repeater:

```
Text='<%# "Entry: " +  ((<class name storing database values>)Container.DataItem).Entry%>'>
```

To concatenate a string with a database entry outside a repeater:

```
Text='<%# "Entry: " +  <class name storing database values>.<Get Entry Name Method>%>'>
```

To concatenate a string with a method:

```
Text='<%# "Entry: " +  <method name>%>'>
```

The method should return a string.